# Contourplot of Binomial Distribution

Tags: distributions

Ok, so before anything else, I have no idea what I'm doing. Not in mathematica and maybe not in the maths either.

My question is basically if I can contour-plot `f=BinomialDistribution[100, p]`, with the distribution f (in colour) along the y-axis, and the chance p for the distribution along the x-axis. I would give some MWE if I got anything to work, but sadly I don't. I did create an image of how I somewhat expect it to look.

[image: Example of my proposed image]

So what I can do is explain the rationale. I'm working on grain count samples, which are usually expressed in concentrations (5% Garnet, 10% Zircon, etc.). One usually counts 100 grains, so every grain turns into 1%. This of course introduces a representation error, due to the difference in *actually present* concentration and *measured* concentration. As far as I know, the Binomial Distribution like `BinomialDistribution[100, 0.2]` gives you the chance of finding the correct concentration (f=0.1 at 20%) as well as the chances for near integers. The distribution obviously peaks at a low percentage and spreads out greatest along the middle 50%.

Thus along the X-axis I have the 'actual concentration', and along the y-axis I have the '(chance of) measured concentration'. given by `BinomialDistribution[100, x/100]`

I hope you understand my question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
ArrayPlot[
 Table[PDF[BinomialDistribution[100, x/100], y], {y, 0, 100}, {x, 0, 100}], 
   DataReversed -> True, FrameTicks -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, yes, great! I didn't know about the PDF function. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Didn't know about `PDF`? It shows up in the very first example in the documentation for `BinomialDistribution` :)